# Como ler um input no laço de repetição

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em C. Preciso que o programa abaixo leia o número digitado em console e dê dicas ao usuário até ele acertar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num;
    printf("Informe um número entre 0 e 10:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while (num!=7)
    {
        printf("Escolha outro valor:");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        switch(num)
        {
            case '0':
                printf("Tente outro numero\n");
                break;
            case '1':
                printf("Escolha outro valor\n");
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("Esta longe, tente outro\n");
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("O numero e maior\n");
                break;
            case '4':
                printf("Tente novamente\n");
                break;
            case '5':
                printf("Esta proximo, mas ainda nao e este\n");
                break;
            case '6':
                printf("Ja pensou em tentar um numero impar?\n");
                break;
            case '8':
                printf("Esta proximo\n");
                break;
            case '9':
                printf("Tente um valor menor\n");
                break;
            case '10':
                printf("E um numero menor\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Voce acertou");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Caro @user31057, dê uma lida no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e edite sua pergunta de forma sucinta, assim a comunidade pode ajudar com sua dúvida mas não fazer seu exercício.

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Quando vou compilar não consigo fazer ele repetir

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância (sou novato em programação), mas ele já não está entre chaves?

Comment: É só tirar as Aspas Simples que vai funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

Como disse @Daniel Gomes, tire as aspas simples. Para este tipo de construção em que o laço deve se repetir ao menos uma vez use `do{} while();` e evite uma verificação desnecessária:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main ()
    {
        int num;

        do
        {

            printf("Informe um número entre 0 e 10:\n");
            scanf("%d",&num);

            switch(num)
            {
                case 0:
                printf("Tente outro numero\n");
                case 1:
                printf("Escolha outro valor\n");
                break;
                case 2:
                printf("Esta longe, tente outro\n");
                break;
                case 3:
                printf("O numero e maior\n");
                break;
                case 4:
                printf("Tente novamente\n");
                break;
                case 5:
                printf("Esta proximo, mas ainda nao e este\n");
                break;
                case 6:
                printf("Ja pensou em tentar um numero impar?\n");
                break;
                case 8:
                printf("Esta proximo\n");
                break;
                case 9:
                printf("Tente um valor menor\n");
                break;
                case 10:
                printf("E um numero menor\n");
                default:
                printf("Voce acertou");
            }
        }while(num != 7);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tirando as aspas simples, seu código rodou normalmente aqui.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num;
    printf("Informe um número entre 0 e 10:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while(num!=7)
    {
        printf("Escolha outro valor:");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        switch(num)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Tente outro numero\n");
            case 1:
                printf("Escolha outro valor\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Esta longe, tente outro\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("O numero e maior\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Tente novamente\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Esta proximo, mas ainda nao e este\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Ja pensou em tentar um numero impar?\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("Esta proximo\n");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("Tente um valor menor\n");
                break;
            case 10:
                printf("E um numero menor\n");
            default:
                printf("Voce acertou");
        }
    }
}
```

Executando:

[image: Execução do programa]

Answer (score 0):

O scanf está fora do laço de repetição. Para que a cada verificação do número, ele solicite que o usuário digite novamente, ele deve estar junto do laço:

```
int main ()
{
    int num;

    while(num!=7)
    {

        printf("Informe um número entre 0 e 10:\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        switch(num)
        {
            case 0:
            printf("Tente outro numero\n");
            case 1:
            printf("Escolha outro valor\n");
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("Esta longe, tente outro\n");
            break;
            case 3:
            printf("O numero e maior\n");
            break;
            case 4:
            printf("Tente novamente\n");
            break;
            case 5:
            printf("Esta proximo, mas ainda nao e este\n");
            break;
            case 6:
            printf("Ja pensou em tentar um numero impar?\n");
            break;
            case 8:
            printf("Esta proximo\n");
            break;
            case 9:
            printf("Tente um valor menor\n");
            break;
            case 10:
            printf("E um numero menor\n");
            default:
            printf("Voce acertou");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como o `scanf("%d",&num);` está fora do laço se ele tem dois?

Answer (score -2):

Experimente remover as aspas do seu case:
-> Quando você faz isso  você pede o ao case mais ou menos isso:
 "Case, compare o que tem no meu Switch com o caracter '1' ".
O problema é esse, ao fazer isso você não está comparado 1 com '1', e sim 1 com um valor da tabela ASCII que representa o caracter '1'.
Entendeu?